# What is the most efficient way to dynamically load and unload Javascript plugins?

Tags: javascript, plugins

I would like to know the efficient way to dynamically **load** and **unload** Javascript plugins depending
on options toggled on and off by the user.

Also, I was wondering if all the resources will really be freed if I simply remove the `<script id="pluginId">`
tag from the DOM ?

Thank you!

Comment: When you include a Javascript file, the state of the page is potentially changed. I doubt there is a way to "unload" a Javascript plugin/file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346897/can-dynamically-loaded-javascript-be-unloaded

Comment: Though if everything is attached to a namespace, you could potentially null everything out.  Watch out for the memory leaks though.

Comment: When deleting a `<script>` tag, I can still access the functions which are inside that .js file.

Comment: Great information guys !

Answer (score -1):

You can create a script tag and insert it into the DOM in the header:

```
 var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var script= document.createElement('script');
 script.type= 'text/javascript';
 script.src= 'helper.js';
 head.appendChild(script);
```

Snippet from http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html