# Clean the previous elements after load replacement data with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page and I am using ajax to load the data from a database. That data contains some html code and I put this code inside a div called `#container`.  I have a paginator system, so if I click on "next" button, the ajax starts again and gets the html code as response, and then replaces this code with the previous code inside a `#container`.

I have code something like this:

```
function loading_show() {
    $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
}
function loading_hide() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
}
function loadData(page) {
    loading_show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_data.php",
        data: "page=" + page,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                loading_hide();
                $("#container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The result of the ajax function is a HTML message. A part of this message is something like this:

```
<span id="one_15" class="textzero">8002379154 - JKLM REPRESENTACIONES Y CIA LTDA</span>
```

OO. So.. if I make the ajax call again I get another html like this:

```
<span id="one_16" class="textzero">EXAMPLE TEXT</span>
```

The problem is that, say if I want to do something with `textzero` class after loading before the `textzero` class `preserv` the previous ajax data like this:

```
texto2 = $('.textzero').text();

<span id="one_15" class="textzero">8002379154 - JKLM REPRESENTACIONES Y CIA LTDA</span>
<span id="one_16" class="textzero">EXAMPLE TEXT</span>
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to clean the previous elements after load replacement data with an ajax call?

Comment: What does ` $("#container").ajaxComplete(...)` achieve? It appears to be unnecessary.

Comment: And what do you mean by "clean the previous elements"? Could be interpreted in several ways, none of which makes any sense with regard to the rest of the question.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576618/remove-ajax-loaded-content-and-script

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`$("#container").empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove all child nodes from that container.